# How to write Xpath Pseudo - Element ::before

Tags: selenium

Building a framework & finding difficulty to clicking Pseudo Elements using xpath.

Xpath written:

//*[@placeholder='Search Brand']//following::div[@title='Do']/div/div/label/div[@class='_1p7h2j']

```
    <div class="_4IiNRh" title="Do">
      <div class="_2wQvxh _1WV8jE">
        <div class="_2kFyHg_2Pd_op">
        ::before
        "Do"
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest using css locator where you can locate the elements using the pseudo element. Eg: `div._1p7h2j::before`

Comment: use chropath plugin